# Updating selected data in table/form on change of a field in form with a variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm quite new to MS Access, but I'm trying to set up a database for building management and regulation in MS Access, which is going to be used for energy use modelling of the building. I therefore have multiple tables which i control with forms. There are multiple zones in a building with different occupations, e.g. one zone is offices, the other a recreational area. In those zones are multiple rooms which have the same occupation. I have a form which provides an overview of the zone, with data such as area size, floor nr etc., but also with a list of rooms that are in that zone. The zones with respective occupation and other data are in one table, the list of rooms is a different table.
What I want it to do, is that when I change the occupation of a zone in the overview form, all the rooms in that zone also change to that occupation.

### Info:

Zones table contains fields 'Zone_code', 'Occupation' and non related zone specific data
Rooms table contains fields 'Room_ID', 'In_zone', 'Occupation', and room specific data

I've tried using macro's on the 'Onchange' event, where I would select the table, select the data where the zone are equal, and than set the value to the changed occupation. I've also tried it with selecting the subform of the roomlist. I've also tried using an update query, but I encountered errors updating using a variable.

I had to do the same for the floors, where there are multiple zones per floor and have a table for that overview. I'll show the macro that worked there, but when I used a similar one for the rooms, I got errors such as 'The object doesn't contain the Automation object "Roomlist"'. I even tried update queries but I feel lost.

The macro that worked for the floors where 'main' is the main building table with the floors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/azHTX.jpg

The macro i used for the rooms: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frnts.jpg

I used the iif statement to compare zones and only update if the zones are the same but this macro crashes, other macro's i made only added 1 new room with the new occupation, but nothing else.

I expected the macro to just run down the table of the rooms and change the value of the ones where the zone code is the same. Or at least, that is what i hope the database will do eventually. 
Can somebody help me figure this out so that it works? I feel I'm missing or overlooking one small thing but I don't understand access enough yet to figure out what. I don't mind if the solution uses a completely different aspect of access, as long as it works. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't edit table directly with SetValue method. No, macro will not 'just run down the table'. If you have the occupation in the zone record, should not be necessary to also save it in rooms table - that is duplicating data in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start out by saying welcome to the site and MS Access! To answer your question, I would start by looking at your data setup. As mentioned by June7, having Occupation in both tables independently is not necessary. Think of it this way: if I have a value I want to update (such as in this case with your question), it is much easier to update in one location than in multiple locations. From what you've shared, [Occupation] only applies to the [Zone_Code] table and should be present only in that table. Through the relationship of [Zone_code] to [Room_ID] through the [In_Zone] field, [Occupation] of the zone that the room is part of can now be queried.

Another thing to consider is having a table, say 'tbl_Occupation' or something of the like, where you could have the fields [OccupationID] and [Occupation]. Doing this could make it easier to maintain the occupations for which a zone can be assigned (if the reference name of an occupation changes but it is not a different occupation, etc.), and also stores occupation in one location, so that if an occupation is assigned to multiple zones, the ID is referenced instead.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the welcome and the help. I understand what you mean and I see now that I wasn't completely clear in my explanation. Sorry for that. I want the possibility that the room occupation is different than the zone it is in, as in, the default value should be the same as the zone but it should be possible to give a couple of rooms different values for occupation. For example, toilets, storage rooms and technical rooms. 
In my understanding, if I do it your way, occupation is linked to the zone code, but this can not be altered for a room without altering the occupation for the zone

Comment: @JellevandeKerk, Thank you for further explanation and you are correct in what my answer initially provides. In the case of wanting to have the ability to have separate occupations for both the zone and room, you could have an independent table for [OccupationID] and [Occupation], and then assign and relate occupation ID values to both the zone and room. Another option would be to have an Occupation for the zone, but then possibly have a room field, say [Room_Attribute] or something of the sort, that describes the room usage since the room still is present in an occupational zone.